# How to cluster a highly dense graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have this highly dense graph I want to cluster, I was wondering which is the best algorithm for this case scenario. I'd like to generate a considerable amount of subgroups.

I'm using Python's library [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) to generate the graph.

[image: my graph]

Comment: There are many different clustering algorithms; you'll need to define what you mean by "best".

Comment: @j_random_hacker I mean to find the one that best fits my graph morphology, since subclusters are not rather observable, and if it can be implemented using the library I'm already using, better.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help -- what is "morphology"?  What would help is if you can frame what you want as the optimal value of some function.  If you just want to get a clustering that somehow looks "nice" to you, all I can suggest is trying a few different ones and seeing what you get.

Comment: lookup graph-cut and minimum-cut algorithms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory) If you are not done with your graph yet, but instead you still have to infer structure (add more edges, move nodes/groups of nodes etc) the problem gets even harder.

Comment: What *would* be a "good" clustering? Otherwise, just label points randomly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went for the [Louvain method](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0476.pdf) since it was the best fit for my problem and also there was a [library](http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/) already implemented that speaks with Networkx.